# Bootstrap Carousel Isn't Working When Integrated

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT:  When I click on either the left or the right icons, it just fires me to the bottom of the page.  I imagine it's because of the #truespeed.when I have a standalone carousel page, this works perfectly.  But when I try to add it together with my website I'm designing, it goes downhill.

Edit #2: I just reconfirmed if the carousel coder works on a standalone page, and it does.  I checked all my external page links, and they work fine.  I'm seriously at a loss.

Here's my static page (for navbar, header, and footer):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
        <title>{{var pageTitle}}</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{var protoHost}}FavIconsuperawesome32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{var protoHost}}favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{var protoHost}}css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{var protoHost}}css/print.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{var protoHost}}css/navbar-custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        {{var extraHeaders}}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-3 branding">
                  <a class="imgCon" href="{{var protoHost}}">
                      <img alt="superawesome Internet Services" src="{{var protoHost}}img/SuperAwesomeInternet.png">
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="brandingspacer">
                  <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://www.facebook.com/superawesomeInternetService"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color:#3B5998"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-0">
                  <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://twitter.com/superawesomecanada"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style="color:#1da1f2"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-0">
                  <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://www.instagram.com/superawesomeinternet/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color:#623628"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-0">
                  <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_EH7RNVnL7IUch12iHzFAQ"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x" style="color:#E62B24"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-0">
                  <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://plus.google.com/116264661972220598755"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" style="color:#DB4437"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-0">
                <p class="socialmediaspacer headerspacer inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i><a href="tel:613-865-7733" style="color: black"> 613-865-7733</a></p>
                <p class="headercontact headerspacer inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"><a href="mailto:info@superawesome.ca" style="color: black"></i> info@superawesome.ca</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="inlineParagraph buttonspacer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">My Account</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
                    <div class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block">
                        <button id="btnToggleNavMenu" type="button" name="button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-0 container-fluid" data-expand="false">
                      <p class="inlineParagraph navbartext"><a href="/internet" color="white"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download navIcon fa-lg"></i>View Our Internet Packages!</a></p>
                      <p class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users navIcon fa-lg"></i>Test Services</a></p>
                      <p class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment navIcon fa-lg"></i>Contact Us!</a></p>
                    </div>

            </nav>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="Location inlineParagraph printHide">
                  <form>
                    Please enter your postal code to check for availability:
                    <input type="text" name="locationcheck">
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="smallspacer"></div>
                {{var content}}
            </div>
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
                        <a class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
                        <a class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
                        <a class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
                        <a class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
                        <a class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>&copy; 2016 superawesome Internet Services - All Rights Reserved</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{var protoHost}}js/navCode.js"></script>
        {{var extraScripts}}

    </body>
</html>
```

And when I add my carousel code into my home page, all the Glyph icons pop up, and the circles at the bottom.  But none of them work at all.

My home page code:

```
    <?php
    $this->setExtraHeader('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{var protoHost}}css/home.css">');
    $this->setExtraHeader('<meta name="description" content="superawesome is a brockville Internet and Phone provider for your needs. Let\'s get connected!">');
?>
<div class="contactspacer"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="superawesomeslider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- indicators dot nov -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#superawesomeslider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#superawesomeslider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
              <img src="img/Internet.jpg" alt="Internet Services" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>superawesome Internet Services</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/Phone.jpg" alt="superawesome Internet Services" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Phone</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls or next and prev buttons -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#superawesomeslider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#superawesomeslider" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas with what is going on?

Comment: could you provide some way to test it?

Comment: I'm trying to, but JSfiddle has always hated me.

Comment: @ThomasHutton Try adding it using the Code Snippet feature of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MattD Hi Matt, I'm still having issues running them.  Since it's running off of an PHP engine I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! It was in my bootstrap.min.js link.

It WAS:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But when you're linking locally, integrity and crossorigin mess it up, so I removed them, and BAM!  It works.

Huzzah!